# Can I apply funds to a credit card

Tags: credit-card

I just got approved for a MasterCard. It was only for 300. Can I increase that amount by adding my own extra money to it

Answer (score 0):

You can send money to the bank and create a *credit balance*, but you cannot increase the *credit limit*.  So if you send them $100, you can then charge $400 in one transaction.

That said, I see no practical benefit to doing this.  If you want to buy something that's $400 and only have $100, just pay $100 in cash and charge the other $300.  Or save up and pay in cash :)